# Ruby on Rails: not authorized to access sign up page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I have devise and CanCan set up, but I'm trying to get into sign up page in my rails application, but its redirecting me to home page saying that I'm not authorized to access this page.

I have a custom registration controller:

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  before_filter :check_permissions, :only => [:new, :create, :cancel]
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication

  def check_permissions
    authorize! :create, resource
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @profile = Profile.new

  end 

  def update
    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
        params[:user].delete(:password)
        params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end

  end

  protected
    def after_update_path_for(resource)
      user_path(resource)
    end

  private

end
```

It has something to do with `before_filter :check_permissions,...` because when I delete this line, I get an error saying

```
undefined method `user_registration_path'
```

from my registration form in my `devise/registrations#new:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

How do I fix my registration form?

Also, this is my routes:

```
  devise_for :user, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }, :skip => [:registrations, :sessions] do 
    get 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration 
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay from what it looks like you've done is used CanCans `authorize!` method to handle the authorization in a controller action which will raise the cancan exception error. Can you not try and do

```
  check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?
```

I back this up with a change made a cancan commit seen here [adding :if and :unless options to check_authorization - closes #284](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/commit/80f1ab20fb880d9d995da5dc25708a8be1e9671c#L0R246). Comments can be seen in the following issue: [GitHub issue 284](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/284). Where Ryan states:

> It would be nice if the check_authorization method allowed a block to dynamically customize the behavior. If it returned true it would perform the authorization.

Correct me if I am wrong but is this not what you are trying to do. Hopefully this sheds some light.

Another thing with regards to your `routes.rb` where you have done:

```
 devise_for :user, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }, :skip => [:registrations, :sessions] do 
    get 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration 
  end
```

This all looks a bit mis-match to me. Do you have by any chance a `devise` folder containing all devise controllers in your controller directory. If so could you not try and make your devise route block look like the following:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'devise/sessions', :registrations => 'devise/registrations', :passwords => 'devise/passwords'}, :skip => [:sessions] do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    get '/register' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :registrations
    post '/login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

**update**
From the link [GitHub - CheckAuthorization](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L229-255)I pasted in my comment I believe you can the method `check_authorization` as the example shows you can do:

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    check_authorization
  end
```

The controller then shows that you can:

> Supply the name of a controller method to be called. The authorization check only takes place if this returns false.

```
     check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm supposed to add a new file to my application or am I supposed to modify an existing cancan file to implement the check_authorization?

Comment: Yea, but I don't have a cancan folder in my lib folder. Sorry, I'm new to RoR still

Comment: @andrewliu you don't need to have the `lib/controller_additons` if you look at the following https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L229-255 have a read of it and see my update